# Iterating over a list in python using for-loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iteration

I have a question about iterating over a list in python. 
Let's say I have a list: `row = ['1', '2', '3']` and want to convert its element to integers, so that: `row = [1, 2, 3]`.

I know I can do it with list comprehension:

```
row = [int(i) for i in row]
```

or for-loop:

```
for i in range(len(row)):
    row[i] = int(row[i])
```

My question concerns `range(len(row))` part. Can someone answer in layman friendly way, why I can do something like this:

```
for i in row:
    print(i)
```

But I can't do this:

```
for i in row:
    row[i] = int(row[i])
```

Comment: Try running `['1', '2']['1']` in the interpreter. Can you use strings as lists' indices?

Comment: this will help https://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. I thought that `for i` works on indexes, so it goes from first to last element, without getting its value, just like in list comprehension.

Comment: `i` is just an arbitrary variable name, it doesn't affect what's going on. You can call it `banana` and it all works the same.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What I meant is that in for-loop, that variable `i` or `banana` takes values of list elements, so if list is `['3',1'','2']`, first `i` would have value of `3`, but in list comprehension which uses same `for i in` first `i` is `0`

Comment: @mykoza no, it is not. list comprehensions work **exactly the same**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok, thank you, my bad then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `for i in row`, `i` takes the values in `row`, i.e. `'1'`, then `'2'`, then `'3'`.

Those are strings, which are not valid as a list index. A list index should be an integer. When doing `range(len(row))` you loop on integers up to the size of the list.

By the way, a better approach is:

```
for elt_id, elt in enumerate(list):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: In addition, even if converted, an index out of range error would throw due to the first val not being 0.

Comment: @dfundako Yeah the conversion is not a good idea, especially since it could work because of its example with values which could be indexes, but it could also be something else...

Comment: Can you explain `for elt_id, elt in enumerate(list):`? What are `elt_id, elt`?

Comment: @Gigaflop Doing `for i in range(len(list)):` is bad practice. A better way is to use `enumerate()` which will return a tuple `(id, elt)`. Thus using enumerate, you get both the id and the element at each iteration. It is equivalent to: `for id in range(len(list)): elt = list[id]`

Comment: @Mathieu Thanks for providing another way of doing this. Is your approach only better than for-loop, or also better than list comprehension?

Comment: @mykoza It is better that using `range(len(list))` but it also uses a for loop. And it can be incorporated in a list comprehension. You have 3 scenarios: 1 you need to iterate on the element in the list, then simply use `for elt in list:`, 2 you only need the indexes, 3 you will need the indexes and the element. For these 2 last, it's better to use an `enumerate` than a `range(len(list))`

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
for i in row:
    row[i] = int(row[int(i)])
```

i is the element in the array `row`. Therefore, `i` will be '1' then '2' then '3'.

But indexes have to be integers and i is a string so there will be an error.

---

If you do:

```
for i in row:
    row[int(i)] = int(row[i])
```

It will still be an error because i is the integer of element in the array `row`. Therefore, i will be 1 then 2 then 3.

But `row[3]` will cause a `IndexError` because there are only 3 elements in the list and numbering starts from 0.

---

While in the other case(the first case), `i` becomes 0 then 1 then 2 which does not cause an error because row[2] is valid.

---

The reason is :

> range() is 0-index based, meaning list indexes start at 0, not 1. eg.
>   The syntax to access the first element of a list is mylist[0] .
>   Therefore the last integer generated by range() is up to, but not
>   including, stop .

Comment: Thanks, for your answer! Can you tell me why in seemingly same construct: `for i in row`, there are two different ways of handling the `i`? What I mean is that in loop, `i` takes values from list, but in list comprehension it starts from 0?

Comment: Thank you for elaborating, but I didn't mean `range()` function. What I was saying was that in list comprehension `[sth for i in list]`, `i` starts from 0, but in loop `for i in list:  sth`, `i` takes the value of `list` element

Comment: @mykoza `row = [int(i) for i in row]` also starts i from 1 upto 3(which are the elements of the list) but it creates a new list named row which has `int(i)` where i is every element in the list row. So the new list becomes `row = [int("1"), int("2"), int("3")]`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example from IDLE:

```
>>> row = ['1', '2', '3']
>>> for i in row:
    row[i] = int(row[i])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 2, in <module>
    row[i] = int(row[i])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

The items being iterated over are not integers, and cannot be used as an index to the list.

The following will work for some of the time, but throw an `IndexError` at the end:

```
for i in row:
    i2 = int(i)
    row[i2] = i2
```

Answer (score 2):

Given `row = ['1', '2', '3']`, each item inside row is a string, thus it can be easily printed:

```
for i in row:
    print(i)
```

However, in your second example you are trying to access row using a string. You need an integer to access values inside a list, and row is a list! (of strings, but a list still).

```
for i in row:
    # row[i] = int(row[i])  -> this will throw an error
    row[int(i)] = int(row[int(i)]) # this will throw an error
```